# Use Unity Addressables without including the Addressable in the build?

Tags: unity-game-engine, addressables

In our game, we have a ton of user-generated content--UGC--that we want to allow the user to download via Addressables in our Unity game because it's not feasible to include every `.asset` that is generated in our build. They build these `.asset`s in the game. The problem is that the only way I know how to generate an Address for that specific  `.asset` itself is by dragging it into Unity, then marking it as Addressable.

The UGC is currently stored on S3, and if I can include an Address to it via the catalog without having it in the Unity repository I can use Addressables (as long as the RemoteLoadPath is set correctly). I'm not sure if this is possible though, and if Addressables is not meant for this.

Perhaps what I want to do would be better served by AssetBundles or using a `UnityWebRequest` with a URL to S3 where the build doesn't need to know anything about the `.asset` that needs to be included. I would have to manage loading/unloading myself but that is fine--I can figure that out. This is just for a proof of concept.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you considered unitys ugc?

Comment: I haven't, I wasn't even aware of it, I am looking into it now actually

Comment: im not saying its the answer but if it is, no point reinvrenting wheels